# Trouble using PnPJS for SharePoint Term Store in SPFx

Tags: spfx, typescript, pnpjs

I'm developing a SharePoint Framework (SPFx) application and am trying to interact with the SharePoint Term Store using the Patterns and Practices JavaScript Core Library (PnPJS). I'm using a version of PnPJS released after v2.

I initially tried to use the @pnp/sp-taxonomy package, only to find out that it was removed after PnPJS v1.3.11. In my code, I'm trying to access the term store using sp.termStore, but I'm encountering an error saying: "Property 'termStore' does not exist on type 'SPRest'".

Here's a simplified snippet of my code:

```
    import { sp } from '@pnp/sp';
import '@pnp/sp/taxonomy';

// ...

private async getTermsFromTermSetAsync(termSetId: string): Promise<Term[]> {
    // ...

    const cachedTermInfo = await this.store.local.getOrPut(this.myKey, () => {
      return sp.termStore.groups.getById(groupId).sets.getById(setId).getAllChildrenAsOrderedTree({ retrieveProperties: true });
    }, dateAdd(new Date(), "minute", 10));
    // ...
}
```

I understand that this issue might be due to the removal of @pnp/sp-taxonomy, but I'm not sure how to work around this issue. I've read about a potential new @pnp/sp-term-store package, but couldn't find clear documentation or examples on how to use it.

Could anyone provide some guidance or sample code on how to interact with the SharePoint Term Store using a recent version of PnPJS?

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!